# Need help to Pass Message from popup.html to content.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I am new to coding, and am still a bit shaky on this message passing business. I want an onclick function to insert the textarea from my popup.html into a specific place in my content.js. In doing so, it would take out that specified word on all webpages and replace it with the word submitted from the second box (`myFunction1()`). If possible, if there is a way to `onClick` submit what's in the text area and write it onto the popup.html, or post it on an options page, that would be very helpful as well. Here's what I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My extension",
    "description": "help!",
    "version": "0.1",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons": { "19" : "icon.png",
     "48" : "logo45.png",
     "128" : "logo120.png"},


  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "My Extension",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ],


  "permissions" : [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"mycontentscript"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
  if(message.greeting === "hello"){

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(id="**demo**"/gi, id="**demo1**");
            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value=" word">
<input type="text" id="myText1" value=" word2">

<button onclick="myFunction();myFunction1()">Thanks!</button>

<p id="demo">
  <p id="demo1">

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
};

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  'method': 'getInfo'
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
});
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to submit the text from `myText1` and `myText` to place it where it is bolded in the content.js. I want the submitted text to remain running for as long as the function is still enabled. Also, for some reason, the place where I insert the text back onto the popup ( ) is not showing up. Is there any way to do these things?

Comment: Forgot to specify, the last snippet is from the popup.html and the popup.js

Comment: Not quite, this question involves text areas and inserting and an Id= within a js function.

Comment: Once you fix the main issue you might get everything else easily solved (arguably).

Comment: Also, it's the wrong messaging function. Do read the [messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: ...and see [the answers on stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/?#q=site:stackoverflow.com+google-chrome-extension+send+message+from+popup+to+content&tbs=qdr:y)